# Is there way to get chrome to show the size of an asset even though it was fetched from disk cache?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

In the chrome developer tools network panel, the size column just shows `(disk cache)` for cached resources. This is helpful to know but sometimes I'd still like to know what the size of that asset is regardless of whether it was fetched or found in cache.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: Enable `Big request rows` in the panel's settings toolbar.

Comment: @wOxxOm oh perfect, hadn't noticed that toggle before. Can you post that as an answer so I can accept it?